# Improved audit trail availability for the Asset type entities of the Hyperledger Composer framework

Tags: hyperledger-composer

An asset's audit trail, consisting of its creation transaction and all its update transactions, should be retrievable in an easy and efficient manner.

For the purpose of query based access, such transactions would probably need to pack an extra array, storing the corresponding assets’ identities, similar to the "resources" array, making it possible to query as below:
    SELECT org.hyperledger.composer.system.UpdateAsset
    WHERE (resourcesIdentities CONTAINS 'assetId')

Same capability should be available for all modifiable entity type, e.g. the Participant type.

Answer (score 0):

we currently have an issue https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2458 that you can add your comments or +1 the proposal as you wish. It also has interim methods posted there in the comments near the end FYI.

query UA {
description: "Select all JunkAssets"
  statement:
  SELECT org.hyperledger.composer.system.UpdateAsset 
  WHERE ( targetRegistry == 'resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AssetRegistry#org.acme.trading.JunkAsset' )
} 
```
- you can check/compare the asset id in `resources` from your result set something like shown here `console.log('Resources for asset trxn identifier found: ' +  asset.resources[0].id )` and compare if it matches (the asset id could be passed separately to your function by the calling trxn - you would do a match for the id in resources array - if true, grab trxn id etc - the CONTAINS query route on this `resources` array field won't work).